# why scroll left is not working for negative value?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, click

My design have three blocks three on top and one at bottom below middle.

Left <--------> Middle<---------->Right

-----------------Bottom------------------

I have two questions.

1. Why scroll left is not working for negative values. (left click of section2)
   (i get `$('#section1').offset().left == -4000`)
2. How can i used `scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top` for top-bottom section.

#### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/buwn5yra/2/)

Html code

```
<div class="section white" id="section1" style='margin-left: -4000px;'>
            <h2>Section 1</h2>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#section2">Right</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="section black" id="section2">
            <h2>Section 2</h2>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#section1">Left</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section4">Bottom</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section3">Right</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="section white" id="section3">
            <h2>Section 3</h2>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#section2">Left</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="section_vertical white" id="section4">
            <div style="width:33%; margin: 0 auto">
                <h2>Section 4</h2>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#section2">up</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

jquery

```
        $('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
            var $anchor = $(this);
             $('html, body').stop().animate({
                  scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
              }, 3000);
             event.preventDefault();
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer 1**

Left position of body, html can not be negative.

Instead:

```
1. in id="section1" remove style='margin-left: -4000px;'
2. add $('html, body').scrollLeft(4000) that section 2 comes into view
```

http://jsfiddle.net/buwn5yra/3/

**Answer 2**

**JQ:**

```
$('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    var t=$(id).offset().top;  // get top position
    var l=$(id).offset().left; // left left position

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: l,
        scrollTop: t                        
    }, 3000);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**HTML:**
in section4 remove style="width:33%; margin: 0 auto". This style places content in the middle, so it does not show when you scroll to this section. Section4 is 100% width.

http://jsfiddle.net/buwn5yra/5/

Answer 2 UPDATE:

http://jsfiddle.net/buwn5yra/7/

```
$('ul.nav a').bind('click', function (event) {
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    var t = $(id).offset().top;
    var l = $(id).offset().left;

    if(id=="#section4") l=$(this).parents('.section_vertical').left;

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: l,
        scrollTop: t
    }, 3000);
    event.preventDefault();
});


$('html, body').scrollLeft(4000)
```

Comment: thnaks for my first answer. can u help for second answer? Is that any wrong in margin-left:-4000px?

Comment: I added an answer to the second question

Comment: @dn4web i want section4 below section2. and Same width as others. thats why added `style="width:33%; margin: 0 auto" `see my design in question.

Comment: I added changes: Answer 2 UPDATE